# How to keep redux state when page refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

Following Dan Abramov method for storing state in localStorage I am unable to retain the existing state of my app after carrying out a page refresh. Using redux dev tools, when I log in, state is authenticated and user is stored. When the page is refreshed the log just clears and goes back to "@@INIT"

My code for index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
import { loadState, saveState } from './localStorage';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const middleware = [thunk];
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  thunk
});

const persistedState = loadState();
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  persistedState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

store.subscribe(() => {
  // saves states to localStorage everytime state changes
  saveState(store.getState());
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

code for localStorage.js

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = state => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    console.log('this is the state', state);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore errors
  }
};
```

Comment: could you test that your localStorage works as intented?, e.g. use `throw err` in your try catch code block instead of returning undefined

Comment: @Kunukn I've placed a console.log(err) on each of the catch code but there seems to be no log in the console log at all after refresh of the page.

Comment: Silly me I've been using the dev tools incorrectly, my sincere apologies! @Kunukn Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

// Ignore errors

Don't Ignore the errors, at least log them to see if the state is being set in localstorage or giving some error.

Also Can you confirm that the state is being saved in the localStorage at the first place?

Comment: When I log in, console.log returns the localStorage items. But when I refresh nothing appears in the console at all. Maybe the store is not reloading on refresh? Seems odd.

Comment: Silly me I've been using the dev tools incorrectly, my sincere apologies! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: No issues, glad that you found a way out, just update your question so that anyone else looking for the same problem can find a way out :)

Answer (score 0):

Realised I was using the redux dev tools incorrectly. Following Dan Abramov tutorial helps but a good recommendation is to log the errors which is where I realised I was working correctly. My fault was that I was using the redux inspector, not log monitor!